# How to text before a gridcolumn datafield

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi I am getting a piece of data from my database that I am filling it into a grid. That part works fine.  Now I want to add a URL before this data in DataField. The Data is called "RoutingNumber" I tried doing this with my code.

```
<ComponentArt:GridColumn DataField='http://twilio.liquidus.net/handleincomingcall.ashx?call=<%# Eval("RoutingNumber")%>' HeadingText="URL"   />
```

So I want it to look like this is the datagrid:
http://twilio.liquidus.net/handleincomingcall.ashx?call=8473981500

Where 'http://twilio.liquidus.net/handleincomingcall.ashx?call=' is just text, and the RoutingNumber is tacked on at the end.

My question is how do I add text to a gridcolumn before I use the Data I get from the stored Procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `GridTemplateColumn` as :

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="Call" DataType="System.Int32" 
    FilterControlAltText="Filter Call column" HeaderText="" 
    SortExpression="Call" UniqueName="Call">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="http://twilio.liquidus.net/handleincomingcall.ashx?call=<%# Eval("Call") %>" title="Get call"><asp:Label ID="lblCallId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Call") %>'></asp:Label></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```